# Why does assigning a vector from a factory function and iterating over it inside a loop cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdvector

I wrote a function that decomposes a number into a sequence of smaller numbers such that the sum of the squared sequence elements equals the square of the input number. The declaration of this function looks like this: `std::vector<long long> Decomp::decompose(long long n);`. To test the output of the function, I use the following `main` function:

```
int main()
{
    for (long long n = 1; n <= 65; ++n)
    {
        auto res = Decomp::decompose(n);
        if (res.empty())
            std::cout << n << ": No solution.\n";
        else
        {
            std::cout << n << ": [";
            for (long long i: res)
                std::cout << i << ' ';
            std::cout << "\b]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

However, this leads to a segmentation fault for `n=8`:

```
Output:
1: No solution.
2: No solution.
3: No solution.
4: No solution.
5: [3 4]
6: No solution.
7: [2 3 6]
8: [5 4 3 2 1 0 72405692564177152 72340172838076673 281474993553665 130961 139767842405240 139767842405240 4366240942559068160 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 282578800148737 1099511628033 256 72340168526266368 72340172838091928 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72057594054770689 72340173837828353 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72405692564177153 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 16843009 240 32 17817984 4 272 32 0 3 304 48 0 4 3 2 72339069014704384 130609 257 130593 0 0 0 0 0 0 282574488404224 72340168543109376 0 0 0 0 0 0 72339069031481344 72339073326448640 72058697861300225 257 0 0 0 0 72057598349672448 72058697861300225 72340172838011137 72058697861366017 282578783305985 65793 0 0 1103806595072 282578783305985 72340172821299457 282578800148737 72340168526332161 72340168543109376 72340172838076673 72339069031481600 282578800148481 72340168526332160 72340168543109376 72340172838076673 72339069031481600 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72339069031481344 72339073326448641 72340172838076673 72057598349737985 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 72340172838076673 282578800148737 130145 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (whole lot of zeros...)  Segmentation fault
```

I suspect something in above `main` function is causing the segfault, since the following `main` function seems to work fine:

```
int main()
{
    long long n = 8;
    auto res = Decomp::decompose(n);
    if (res.empty())
        std::cout << n << ": No solution.\n";
    else
    {
        std::cout << n << ": [";
        for (long long i: res)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << "\b]\n";
    }
}

Output:
8: No solution.
```

Edit: 
gdb says the following:

```
Core was generated by `./test'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004026e3 in main ()
```

`Decomp::decompose` looks like this:

```
std::vector<long long> Decomp::decompose(long long n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return std::vector<long long>();

    size_t rows = n - 1, cols = n * n + 1;
    bool *table = new bool[rows * cols];
    std::vector<long long> ret;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        table[i * cols] = true;

    table[1] = true;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < rows; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 1; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            table[i * cols + j] = (j < (i + 1) * (i + 1)) ? 
                                  table[(i - 1) * cols + j] :
                                  table[(i - 1) * cols + j] ||
                                  table[(i - 1) * cols + j - (i + 1) * (i + 1)];
        }

    if ( table[rows * cols - 1] )
    {
        backtrace(n, rows - 1, cols - 1, table, ret);
        std::reverse(ret.begin(), ret.end());
    }

    delete[] table;
    return ret;
}
```

`Decomp::backtrace` is a recursive function that extracts the sequence from the table created in `decompose`, just adding it here for reference:

```
bool Decomp::backtrace(long long n, size_t i, size_t j, bool table[], std::vector<long long> &seq)
{
    if (std::inner_product(seq.begin(), seq.end(), seq.begin(), 0LL) == n * n)
        return true;

    size_t cols = n * n + 1;

    if (table[i * cols + j])
    {
        if ((i + 1) * (i + 1) <= j)
        {
            seq.push_back(i + 1);
            if (backtrace(n, i - 1, j - (i + 1) * (i + 1), table, seq))
                return true;

            return backtrace(n, i - 1, j, table, seq);
        }
        else
        {
            while (table[i * cols + j] and (i + 1) * (i + 1) > j)
                --i;

            if (table[i * cols + j])
            {
                seq.push_back(i + 1);

                if (backtrace(n, i - 1, j - (i + 1) * (i + 1), table, seq))
                    return true;

                return backtrace(n, i - 1, j, table, seq);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "case found\n";
                seq.pop_back();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        seq.pop_back();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the class header for reference:

```
public:
    static std::vector<long long> decompose(long long n);
private:
    static bool backtrace(long long n, size_t i, size_t j, bool table[], std::vector<long long> &seq);
```

Comment: Have you debugged to find out which bit is causing a segfault?

Comment: What does `Decomp::decompose()` look like?

Comment: @John3136, I added the gdb output to the post

Comment: @cantordust I added the sources

Comment: Obviously, your `Decomp::decompose(8)` does something different if it was called after `Decomp::decompose(n)` with `n=1,...7` than if it was called first thing. So, the bug is in this function somewhere. Though this is NOT a debugging service.

Comment: You're right, I'll try to investigate myself. The reason I posted the question was in case I missed something obvious. I'll delete the post if more people share the same sentiment.

Comment: Btw, it's very confusing to have a member `table()` and an automatic variable of the same name within a member function ...

Comment: I'd say one of your unsigned vars (probably `i`) reaches `0` and wraps around. Try adding a breakpoint, say, at the `while` loop and see what the value of `i` is at each iteration.

Comment: My guess was also an invalid array index. gdb is good if you can find it that way, or valgrind is another helpful option for this sort of thing.

Comment: @cantordust and others, thanks for the good suggestions. The problem turned out to be quite trivial, see my anwer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `auto res = Decomp::decompose(n);` it returns a res object with junk values. Consider this output `8: [5 4 3 2 1 0 72405692564177152 72340172838076673.....` after 0 all are seems to be junk value. So put some condition and break loop `for (long long i: res)` or correct `Decomp::decompose(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

After a debugging session, I found the problem: the `bool *table` variable was initialized to garbage values in this line: `bool *table = new bool[rows * cols];`. I expected this to initialize the bools to false. The nonzero garbage values tricked the program into thinking there was a solution for `n=8` and thus calling `backtrace`. However, `backtrace` only works when there is a solution. Otherwise the indexing operations will go out of bounds.

I fixed it by calling the default constructor for `bool` in the table allocation, which sets the bools to false: `bool *table = new bool[rows * cols]();`

Thanks to cantordust for suggesting to try breakpoints.

Comment: Glad you made it work. I would suggest using `std::vector<bool>(rows * cols, false)` to get an efficient array with all values initialised to `false`.

Comment: @cantordust That would probably be for the best. As an added bonus I don't need to worry about freeing the memory afterwards :)

Comment: Actually, using a std::vector slows down the program a bit, especially for large `n` since the table (and the amount of indexing operations) grows as O(n^3).

Comment: Interesting. `std::vector<bool>` should be optimised to occupy a single bit for each element. You could also try using `std::bitset`.

Comment: It's strange indeed, std::vector should be about as fast as a regular array. When I first tried to use a vector, I passed it by value in the `backtrace` function. I later changed it to pass by reference, but the array implementation is still about three times faster than the vector implementation.